# Java Fx Drag and Drop to windows explorer - gestureTarget is always null / explorer should wait

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop, javafx, explorer

I have some problems with implementing drag & drop from my project to explorer.
In my project i have access to some cloud storages e.g. dropbox. 
The problem: when i'm starting drag and drop i don't know if the file should be dropped in my project or in explorer. So if the file is dropped in my project i don't need any download but if the file is dropped in explorer i have to start a download.

Is there a way to tell the os that it should wait for an action in the onDragDone function?
Alternatively i wanted to get the gestureTarget so that i know to witch path the file was dropped and start the download afterwards to this path.
But even if a file transfer succeded the gestureTarget is always null.

Has anyone had this problem, too?
Or has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell the os that it should wait for an action in the onDragDone function?

In native langs IAsyncOperation is used. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#async).

> I wanted to get the gestureTarget so that i know to witch path the file was dropped.

There is no way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i don't know how to transfer this into java. I tried to do this with the interface AsyncOperation but it only blocks both, my application and the explorer, and nothing is going on.
Do you know a way to do this in javafx?

Comment: Sorry but I don`t have any skill in javafx.